# delete row id using Contentprovider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am using provider to delete all data in `SQLiteOpenHelper` table suppose i have 5 row and i deleted data in table , if i filled table again with data `_ID` column start at 6

**SQLite TABLE**

```
  final String HISTORY = "CREATE TABLE " + Contract.History.TABLE + " (" +
            Contract.History._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            Contract.History.ROW + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Contract.History.HISTORY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";
```

**DELETE SNIPPET IN PROVIDER**

```
 @Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    final int match = matcher.match(uri);
    int rowsDeleted;
    if ( null == selection ) selection = "1";
    switch (match) {

        case HISTORY:
            rowsDeleted = db.delete(
                    Contract.History.TABLE, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }
    // Because a null deletes all rows
    if (rowsDeleted != 0) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }
    return rowsDeleted;
}
```

**HOW I DELETE**

```
 ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
      resolver.delete(Contract.Running.CONTENT_URI,null,null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regular database behavior, and it is not an error in the code or the query, it is just how the SQLite works. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) site states:

> SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID that a table has ever held
>   using an internal table named "sqlite_sequence". The sqlite_sequence
>   table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table
>   that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created. The content of the
>   sqlite_sequence table can be modified using ordinary UPDATE, INSERT,
>   and DELETE statements. But making modifications to this table will
>   likely perturb the AUTOINCREMENT key generation algorithm. Make sure
>   you know what you are doing before you undertake such changes.

I would advise against changing, unless you really know what you are doing. But if you want you can do it like this:

```
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = '<YOUR_TABLE>';
```

You can also update the sequencer, in case you delete only some rows.

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = <n> WHERE name = '<YOUR_TABLE>'
```